# How to verify XML node value to xs:union

Tags: xml, xsd

For the given XSD below:

```
<xs:element name="jeans_size">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:union memberTypes="sizebyno sizebystring" />
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="sizebyno">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
    <xs:maxInclusive value="42"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="sizebystring">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="10"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="11"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="12"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

We have a XML node:

```
<jeans_size>10</jeans_size>
```

How does XSD engine determine which type is that `10`? `xs:union` means `or`, so it's either `xs:positiveInteger` or `xs:string`. Do we represent a `string` as `<jeans_size>'10'</jeans_size>` in XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-union:

> The order in which the ·memberTypes· are specified in the definition (that is, the order of the  children of the  element, or the order of the QNames in the memberTypes attribute) is significant. During validation, an element or attribute's value is validated against the ·memberTypes· in the order in which they appear in the definition until a match is found.

In your case, 10 is `xs:positiveInteger`.